# Method to see jQuery files are loaded completely then execute the function related to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Method to see jQuery files are loaded completely then execute the function related to it

I want to show my div only when all the jQuery files related to that div is loaded.

document ready and window load function doesn't work.

How to write a conditional function where u can check whether all the jQuery is loaded then show the div.... i am calling all my jQuery files in an external js file, (basically i am trying to create a plugin for my client so that my external.js file will work from my server remotely).

my external.js file goes like this:

```
  if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

  }

  if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'js/fancybox.js';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 }

 document.ready = function() {
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#addimage").html("<a id='fancybox' href='large"+clientID+".jpg'><img border=0 src='thumb"+clientID+".jpg'/></a>");

 }
 });
```

so i want this addimage div work only my jquery files is loaded completely

Comment: how come document ready does not work ??
it must work

Comment: @AymanJitan It doesn't work because OP is adding the a script element containing the jQuery library dynamically to the DOM, his script will keep executing while the jQuery library is loaded asynchronously. The `$` is `undefined` by the time it executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
if (jQuery) {  
  // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
  // jQuery is not loaded
}
```